# Select either a column or another based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I need to select rows from a column (`A`) if it's not `nan` else from a another column (`B`), how to do this in Python?

The use case is that I'm inserting a new column `C` that will contain the result of an operation (`func`)  on values from column `A`. Sometimes the values in `A` are `nan`, and in these cases I want to calculate the value in `C` from `B`, an example of the result would be this:

```
|   A   |   B       |   C           |
|   bla |   bla2    |   func(bla)   |  #read from A
|   nan |   bla3    |   func(bla3)  |  #read from B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `combine_first`:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].combine_first(df['B']).apply(func)
```

No explicit iteration required here...

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve your problem.

```
df['C'] = [x['B'] if x['A'] == 'nan' else x['A'] for x in df.iterrows()]
```

basically you create a new list by iterating all rows and selecting the correct one, then you add it to de df.

Answer (score 0):

By applying a function to the dataframe that checks for nan before it returns, you have the ability to switch to another value in the same row. It's important to give `axis=1` if you're using apply on a dataframe (all columns) rather than a series (one column)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,-2],'B':[1,2,2]})

def fn(x):
    c = np.sqrt(x['A'])
    if np.isnan(c):
        c = np.sqrt(x['B'])
    return c
df['C'] = df.apply(fn,axis=1)
```